# Structure pointer asigned adress

Tags: c

I am doing some MCU programming and I can't understand some part of the FFT example code. The main problem that I have is understanding declaration : *pointer=&var

```
//definition of new data types
typedef struct {
float  *InBuf;      //!< Pointer to the input buffer
float  *OutBuf;     //!< Pointer to the output buffer
float  *CosSinBuf;    //!< Pointer to the twiddle factors
float  *MagBuf;       //!< Pointer to the magnitude buffer
float  *PhaseBuf;     //!< Pointer to the phase buffer
uint16_t   FFTSize;   //!< Size of the FFT (number of real data points)
uint16_t   FFTStages; //!< Number of FFT stages
} RFFT_F32_STRUCT;

typedef RFFT_F32_STRUCT* RFFT_F32_STRUCT_Handle;


//code 
RFFT_F32_STRUCT rfft;

RFFT_F32_STRUCT_Handle hnd_rfft = &rfft;
```

The question is what will the last code line do? If i rewrite it to a little bit more readable manner last line would be:

```
 RFFT_F32_STRUCT* hnd_rfft= &rfft;
```

So what is the use of this operation? I would understand, if it  would be written like this:

```
 RFFT_F32_STRUCT* hnd_rfft;
 hnd_rfft=&rfft;
```

I understand it is quite hard to tell, because it is only a part of the code, but if someone sees the reason I would be very glad if he could share it with me.

Comment: `RFFT_F32_STRUCT* hnd_rfft = &rfft;` just combines the variable declaration `RFFT_F32_STRUCT* hnd_rfft;`  and the assignment `hnd_rfft = &rfft;` into a single statement.

Comment: Have you ever written `int x = 5;` instead of `int x; x = 5;`?

Comment: Thank you, both answers were helpful. I thought that * is part of the variable but as i see, it is actually part of data type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I said what that does in english it would be -- define a pointer to point to a location of type RFFT_F32_STRUCT and assign it to point to the address of hnd_rfft

Answer (score 0):

The handle struct is basically "above struct, but in pointer form". So, as defined,

```
RFFT_F32_STRUCT_Handle = RFFT_F32_STRUCT*
```

So you can read it as such:

```
RFFT_F32_STRUCT* hnd_rfft = &rfft;
```

Comment: The problem was, that i thought that this line means:     *hnd_rfft=&rfft
Which wouldn't make any sense.